# Does gz compression ratio improve over time?

Tags: compression, gzip

I have some process that creates a stream of millions of highly similar lines. I'm piping this to `gz`. Does the compression ratio improve over time in such a setup? I.e. is the compression ratio better for 1 million similar lines, than say 10,000?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does up to a certain point and this evens out. The compression algorithms have a restriction on the size of the blocks they look at (`bzip2`) and/or on the tables they keep with information on previous patterns (`gzip`).

In the case of gzip, once a table is full old entries get pushed out, and  compression no further improves. Depending on the your compression quality factor (`-0` to `-9`) and the repetitiveness of your input this filling up can of course can take a while and you might not notice.

Answer (score 4):

Not much. The "distance" covered by the DEFLATE algorithm which `gzip` uses is limited to 32 KB.

[Wikipedia link -> DEFLATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE#Stream_format)

It is worth benchmarking against the various `gzip` compression levels and also considering [bzip2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2) and [xz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [overview of gzip's algorithm](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gzip.git/tree/algorithm.doc?h=v1.10).

Short answer is that it will not improve significantly after the initial data needed for the hashes is taken into account.